# Where or how do people store data in swift for many users to access?

Tags: swift

So I am fairly new and I have a question about data storing. I know about many ways to store local data on individuals devices. But, what do people generally use when making a app that many users access that data that is created.

For example if User 1 creates a list of things, how can that data be stored so many users can look at that list and interact with that list?

Look forward to hearing about data storing answers and tips!

Thanks

Comment: u can checkout Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup - which comes with an online database that all your users can access (internet connection required)

Comment: I concur. Firebase or CloudKit are two good solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of backend. I personally use AWS DynamoDB and Cognito to achieve this. There are many tutorials to help you get started but the documentation is a little outdated and may not make sense for beginners.

Nonetheless, if you want different users to access some sort of shared data, it will need to be stored somewhere that can be accessed by each user (a website, an online database, etc.)

Comment: Or avoid all of that hassle and use CloudKit.

Comment: Yes, that is another backend option that may be easier for beginners to understand. Good idea +1

Comment: I wouldn't call CloudKit easy for beginners. It's not easy for advanced developers. But it eliminates the need to setup a server or get locked into a 3rd party vendor that could disappear at any moment. I wouldn't be surprised if all of the Firebase users suffer the same fate some day that all of those Parse.com users did last year.

Comment: Sorry, by easy I mean what you mentioned, it doesn't require setting up a server and from what I find there is a lot of support for it (stack overflow questions, tutorials, etc) which I believe is super helpful for beginners

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase - extremely easy to use and if you are just displaying strings and integers or images (which most everything is) then it's really user friendly (in my opinion) and it's free as long as you're not hosting 10GB? (I think) or so of data (that's a lot of strings).